# SQL aggregation query and sum columns

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

I have this table (I put the name over needed colums)

```
iddip         date                 idv idc  val
47    2018-06-01 00:00:00.000   0   3   3   60  NULL    NULL
47    2018-06-01 00:00:00.000   0   1   3   200 NULL    NULL
47    2018-06-01 00:00:00.000   0   1   4   280 NULL    NULL
43    2018-06-01 00:00:00.000   0   3   2   510 NULL    NULL
53    2018-06-01 00:00:00.000   0   1   4   480 NULL    NULL
29    2018-06-01 00:00:00.000   0   3   2   510 NULL    NULL
2     2018-06-11 00:00:00.000   0   1   2   480 NULL    NULL
47    2018-06-02 00:00:00.000   0   1   3   100 NULL    NULL
```

I want to obtain this:

```
id idc Totidv1 Totidv3 TOT
47   3     300     60  360
47   4     280      0  280
43   2       0    510  510
53   4     480      0  480
29   2       0    510  510
2    2     480      0  480
```

The closest I can get is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(iddip),IDCENTROCOSTO,tot=SUM(VALORE),ord=( SELECT SUM(isnull(VALORE,0)) FROM VALORIVOCICDC WHERE IDVOCE='1' and iddip=v.IDDIP and IDCENTROCOSTO ='3' GROUP BY iddip,IDCENTROCOSTO),
  str=( SELECT SUM(isnull(VALORE,0)) FROM VALORIVOCICDC WHERE IDVOCE='3' and iddip=v.IDDIP and IDCENTROCOSTO ='3' GROUP BY iddip,IDCENTROCOSTO)
FROM VALORIVOCICDC v
GROUP BY v.iddip,IDCENTROCOSTO
```

But it returns wrong sums in totidv1 and totisv3, How can I do this? Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a GROUP BY here (not distinct) and a couple of CASE statements:

```
SELECT
    id,
    idc,
    SUM(CASE WHEN idv=3 THEN idv ELSE 0 END) as totidv1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN idv=1 THEN idv ELSE 0 END) as totidv3,
    SUM(idv) as Tot
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, idc
```

Note that `Distinct` is not a function that you can call like `SELECT DISTINCT(somecolumn)` This is functionally equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT somecolumn...` in that it works against the entire record set returned by the SELECT statement either way.

Comment: you are my hero, I lost a day on this and the solution is so simple and elegant... thank you! I'll try and mark your answer as the correct one